# Looping through collection and Concatenating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, collections

I want to loop through a collection but instead of manually using Collection.property like CompRes.PartNo1, CompRes.PartNo2,CompRes.Part3 etc and CompRes.Qty1, CompRes.Qty2. I want to get it dynamically.Hence, I use a for-loop, since there are 12 parts and Qty. Please, how can i achieve this using a for-loop and concatenation or if there is a better way to achieve this. See DB and Query Below:
[image]

```
var CompRes = _context.Fleetparts
    .Where(p => (p.FleetModelId == item.FleetmodelId && p.MotivePowerId == item.MotivePowerId
    && p.EngineTypeId == item.EngineTypeId && p.ServiceType == sty.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();


if (CompRes != null)
{
    for (int p = 1; p <= 12; p++)
    {
       var cpartId = string.Format("{0}.{1}{2}", CompRes, "PartNo",p); //CompRes.PartNo1
       var cpartQty = string.Format("{0}.{1}{2}",CompRes, "Qty",p);//CompRes.Qty1
        MrpCreateViewModel model1 = new MrpCreateViewModel
            {
                FltNo = _fleetService.GetById(item.Id).Fltno,
                LocationName = _locationService.GetById(item.LocationId).LocationName,
                FleetModelName = _fleetmodelService.GetById(item.FleetmodelId).ModelName,
                EngineName = _engineTypeService.GetById(item.EngineTypeId).EngineName,
                ServiceType = sty.ToString(),
                ServiceSequence = nsvr,
                EstimatehrPerDay = item.EstimateHrperDay,
                PartNo = _partService.GetById(int.Parse(cpartId.ToString())).PartNo,
                PartName = _partService.GetById(int.Parse(cpartId.ToString())).PartName,
                CostperUnit = _partService.GetById(int.Parse(cpartId.ToString())).CostUOM,

                QtyPerService = int.Parse(cpartQty.ToString()),
                TotalCost = (_partService.GetById(int.Parse(cpartId.ToString())).CostUOM * int.Parse(cpartQty.ToString()))
            };
        MyList.Add(model1);
    }
}
```

Comment: so to get it clear. You select a single item from the collection and want to choose dynamically to loop through the properties? Such things are usually done via reflection. Why do you construct a string from the gathered information? In which format would you like to have it? or need it?

Comment: @MongZhu: Thank. From the DB result image, i need  each PartNo1, PartNo2, PartNo3 up to PartNo12, with Qty1, Qty2 till Qty12. Now, each of the PartNo 1...12 has Id stored in them. So, it is the ID stored that i will use to get the Materials. hence, why i used a for-loop, so that i can do the collectionResult.PartNo and concatenate the Iterator variable

Comment: So, how do i achieve this

Comment: This probably is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and indicates you aren't approaching your actual problem correctly for LINQ to EF, but perhaps if you tell us what you are trying to achieve, we can recommend a better approach.

Comment: @NetMage: I am  trying to  generate a materials for different combination as shown in the  Database Result.

Comment: What are "materials"? There is no mention of "materials" in your code or DB output. Perhaps you could consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and generating string based field access, but again this is unlikely to be the best approach. Of course, your database isn't normalized so you have that issue to deal with. Are you trying to avoid tying your code the an assumption of 12 parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do this sort of thing. Here's an example that will return an enumerable of tuples that contain the property name and value:

```
public IEnumerable<(string propertyName, TProperty value)> GetAllParts<TProperty>(
    object input, string prefix)
{
    // Get all the properties that start with 'prefix'
    var properties = input
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(prefix))
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        // Return the property name and the value
        yield return ($"{property.Name}", (TProperty)property.GetValue(input));
    }
}
```

To use it, let's have a class like this:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public int IntProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty3 { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty4 { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty5 { get; set; }

    public string StringProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty3 { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty4 { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty5 { get; set; }
}
```

Create an instance of it:

```
var thing = new MyThing
{
    IntProperty1 = 1,
    IntProperty2 = 2,
    IntProperty3 = 3,
    IntProperty4 = 4,
    IntProperty5 = 5,
    StringProperty1 = "Value1",
    StringProperty2 = "Value2",
    StringProperty3 = "Value3",
    StringProperty4 = "Value4",
    StringProperty5 = "Value5"
};
```

And finally, get the values we need:

```
var intValues = GetAllParts<int>(thing, "IntProperty");
var stringValues = GetAllParts<string>(thing, "StringProperty");
```

And you can use the results like this for example:

```
foreach (var (propertyName, value) in intValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Property {propertyName} has a value of {value}");
}
```

**Note**: It looks like you are using Entity Framework, if so, methods like this cannot be used by EF, so you need to extract the data from the database into local memory and then call this function.

Comment: If you are using Reflection you should probably cache the `PropertyInfo` objects.

Comment: @NetMage Reflection generally caches the things for you internally anyway, there's rarely much benefit to doing this yourself.

Comment: A lot of code still gets executed to do `GetProperties.Where().ToArray()` including multiple calls to `ToArray`.